# Automapper: complex if else statement in ForMember

Tags: c#, if-statement, automapper

Assuming the `Date` is a nullable `DateTime`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeViewModels, SomeDTO>()               
             .ForMember(dest => dest.Date,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                        {
                            DateTime? finalDate = null;
                            if (src.HasDate == "N")
                            {
                                // so it should be null
                            }
                            else
                            {                                   
                                endResult = DateTime.Parse(src.Date.ToString());
                                
                            }                               
                            return finalDate;

                        }));
```

The error I got was:

> Error 30  A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted
> to an expression tree.

Of course I'm fully aware that I can simplify the query such as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeViewModels, SomeDTO>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.Date,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HasDate == "N" ? null : DateTime.Parse(src.Date.ToString())));
```

But what if I insist to retain the structure of the first example, because I have more complicated if else statements, that the second example will not able to cater for, or at least will not be very readable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`ResolveUsing()`](http://blog.travisgosselin.com/automapper-mapfrom-vs-resolveusing/) method:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeViewModels, SomeDTO>()               
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, o => o.ResolveUsing(Converter));

private static object Converter(SomeViewModels value)
{
    DateTime? finalDate = null;
    if (value.Date.HasDate == "N")
    {
        // so it should be null
    }
    else
    {                                   
        finalDate = DateTime.Parse(value.Date.ToString());
    }                               
    return finalDate;
}
```

Comment: So I will need to define the other properties mapping in the converter even though the rest are straightforward mapping?

Comment: @Sum shortly - yes. but you can map it with automapper inside Converter ignoring this property and set it manualy :) what type is your Date property?

Comment: It is a nullable DateTime, forgot to mention that in my question.
Could you add that example(map it with automapper inside Converter) into your answer as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Sum i was totally wrong :) you can use `ResolveUsing` option with method! it's much easier!

Comment: @Sum the reason why here is MapFrom expects a lambda expression, and you gave it a lambda statement (one with curly braces).

Comment: Since automapper has removed `ResolveUsing` in 8.0+, how do you go from there?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell See my answer.

Answer (score 80):

In recent versions of AutoMapper, `ResolveUsing` was removed. Instead, use a new overload of MapFrom:

```
void MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TResult> mappingFunction);
```

Just adding another lambda/function parameter will dispatch to this new overload:

```
        CreateMap<TSource, TDest>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeDestProp, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
                {
                    TSomeDestProp destinationValue;

                    // mapping logic goes here

                    return destinationValue;
                }));
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped since ResolveUsing was removed!

Comment: This is perfect thanks. I don't know why all these examples are not available or hard to find in AutoMapper official website.

Comment: You're welcome, all. In most cases, I recommend removing AutoMapper and writing hand-written mapping code or even better find a way to avoid copying values in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeViewModels, SomeDTO>()               
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Date,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HasDate == "N" ? "" : DateTime.Parse(src.Date.ToString())));
```