# Automapper mapping generic types

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have 2 generic types that I need to map

```
public class A<T>
{
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class B<T>
{
    public List<T> ResultContent { get; set; }
    public int PropertyC { get; set; }  
}
```

I've tried to map A to B using automapper as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(A<>),typeof(B<>))
    .ForMember("ResultContent", f => f.MapFrom("Results"))
    .ForMember("PropertyC", f => f.MapFrom(?????))
```

It works fine for the `ResultContent` property. However, the issue is that B.PropertyC is a sum of properties A.PropertyA and A.PropertyB. Is it possible to compute mapping of properties for generic types?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use a `converter` and `ResolveUsing()` which will define the operation to be performed.

See for instance this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643076/automapper-complex-if-else-statement-in-formember) for more details.

Comment: I've tried using ResolveUsing, but again I have a trouble passing generic to a custom resolver:

public class Custom_Resolver : ValueResolver<A<???>, int>
    {
        protected override int ResolveCore(A<???> cp)
        {
            return cp.PropertyA + cp.PropertyB;
        }
    }

Comment: The generic type needs to be defined at the Resolver level:

`public class CustomResolver<T> : ValueResolver<A<T>, int>
{
 protected override int ResolveCore(A<T> cp) 
 { 
  return cp.PropertyA + cp.PropertyB;
 }
}`

Comment: Hi Tim, 

Thank you for your help. Yeah I've tried the Resolver that you suggested. It won't work because the resolver is expecting <T> : class while the "Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(A<>),typeof(B<>))" expression has no knowledge that the source type is generic.

Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(A<>),typeof(B<>))
    .ForMember("ResultContent", f => f.MapFrom("Results"))
    .ForMember("PropertyC", f => f.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver<T>>())).  

At the moment I ended up creating multiple mappings for each type that I use with my generic class.

Comment: Well, at some point you have to specify which type you are using. Defining multiple times your mapping is one option, but couldn't you use an interface - IMappable for instance - that A<T> and B<T> would implement?